# R Replacing certain factor levels in data.table with NA

Tags: r, levels

I need to replace factors with the value 0 and 128 in a certain column (LU1945) in a very large data table (val) but as you can see [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451164/removing-factor-level-in-data-table) does not work as the levels are still there when I call levels. I tried NA and 'NA' but still the levels are there.

```
levels(val$LU1945)[val$LU1945== 0] <- NA
levels(val$LU1945)[val$LU1945== 128] <- NA

levels(val$LU1945)[val$LU1945== 0] <- 'NA'
levels(val$LU1945)[val$LU1945== 128] <- 'NA'

#check to see if levels were replaced
levels(val$LU1945)
[1] "0"   "1"   "2"   "3"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "11"  "13"  "14" 
[13] "15"  "128"
```

Comment: `'NA'` is a literal string, it is not the same as R's "null value" of `NA`. Don't use quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `'NA'` is a string literal, not the same as `NA`. Don't use quotes.
2. Replace the *values*, not the levels. (`NA` is native in `factor`s anyway, there's no real need to inject it literally into the levels.)

```r
vec <- factor(1:10)
vec
#  [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
vec[vec %in% c(4, 8)] <- NA
vec
#  [1] 1    2    3    <NA> 5    6    7    <NA> 9    10  
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

You can relevel if you'd like,

```r
vec <- factor(vec)
vec
#  [1] 1    2    3    <NA> 5    6    7    <NA> 9    10  
# Levels: 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10
```

Comment: ok I tried: val$LU1945[val$LU1945 %in% c(0, 128)] <- NA
But they are still there: 
levels(val$LU1945)
                                                                                                                  [1] "0"   "1"   "2"   "3"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9"   "10"  "11"  "13"  "14" 
[13] "15"  "128"

Comment: (1) does `any(val$LU1945 %in% c(0, 128), na.rm=T)` return true or false? (2) what happened when you did my second step, refactoring your data?

Comment: I didn't understand the second suggestion. Wouldn't val$LU1945 <- factor(val$LU1945) just apply the same set of factors onto the vector?

Comment: The first step (`... <- NA`). The second step resets the levels of the factor, so you should no longer see `0` or `128` in your `levels(.)` either.

Comment: Perfect!  val$LU1945 <- factor(val$LU1945) removes the 0 and 128!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't subset `levels` with the vector. Subset `levels` with `levels`.

```
vec <- factor(1:10)
levels(vec)[levels(vec) %in% c(4,8)] <- NA

vec
# [1] 1    2    3    <NA> 5    6    7    <NA> 9    10  
#Levels: 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to remove those values with the `exclude` option of `factor` either when defining `vec` or afterwards:

```r
vec <- factor(1:10, exclude = c(NA, 1, 10))
vec

# [1] <NA> 2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    <NA>
# Levels: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

vec <- factor(1:10)
vec

# [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
# Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

vec <- factor(vec, exclude = c(1, 10))
vec

# [1] <NA> 2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    <NA>
# Levels: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```